# navigate through huge nested array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This might be a simple question, but I am dumping an object ($this) which is absolutely huge and I need to get to a specific point in the array

```
$this->varA->varB->varC->varD->what_I_need
```

I know that the variable that I need is in there and I can use ctrl+f to find it, but the array is so nested that I don't know how I should get to it in PHP. Any ideas on what the best way is to do this?

Comment: You have the data structure from the `var_dump()` so you just need to access it with the correct path - there isn't any special trick.  If you need help, post a sample of the dump here and we can assist you.

Comment: I don't think varB is a property of varA. Are you sure varA isnt an array with sub-arrays under it? Then it would be `$this->varA[varB][...]`

Comment: @Hiroto No point in making any guesses at the structure now.

Comment: I was hoping there a smart way to navigate through the array but here it is:
http://codepad.org/IMNX2LSP

Comment: @Ortix92 And what is it you need to retrieve? Lots of stuff in there is private/protected so you won't be able to get them outside the class.

Comment: Oops I forgot to mention that! My bad! It seems that the first link didn't paste the entire thing. It keeps truncating. Here is a replacement:
http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?2ce425f2956e00ba#lzhtANnBqWGL2t6NRoXQPRUUvjk1xt7Iao5VU2nwAyM=

I am looking for brace_tab_id = 12

Comment: @Ortix92 Looks like `$ProductViewProduct->element->main->brace_tab_id`

Answer (score 1):

Do not hesitate to look at libraries from frameworks.

[CakePHP] made an awesome class which is able to navigate into arrays using a string in dot syntax notation. This library is known as [**Hash**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-utility-libraries/hash.html), just look at it.

If you have this :

```
$var = array(
    'Element1' => array(
        'First_rule' => true,
        'Second_rule' => false,
    ),
    'Element2' => array(
        'First_rule' => 'none',
        'Other_rule' => 'otherone',
    ),
);
```

You can extract datas from this array simply with a string.

You can take only one information from a specific element :

```
$extracted_other_rule = Hash::extract($var, 'Element2.Other_rule');
```

Returns :

```
Array
(
    [0] => otherone
)
```

Or you can even extract all "First_rule" indexes from any element in the array containing it :

```
$extracted_rules = Hash::extract($var, '{s}.First_rule');
```

Returns this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => none
)
```

If you need to navigate through a huge array with undefined depth, just make a recursive function, transferring a string named "$path" to recursive actions. I made a big function of this kind to parse a whole XML stream into a JSON string with all keys parsed with my own rules, with an array of parameters.